# Is the 0 matrix also a projector matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projective-space

Title is basically it - does the 0/null matrix count as a projector matrix?

Comment: If you take a projection to a matrix $A$ such that $A^2=A$, then it is a projection. I guess you think of it as a projection onto the $0$-space

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It projects onto the subspace consisting of the origin.